# Quotes in a different language (Russian)

Tags: languages

Tex prints question marks instead of the russian text that I want it to print. Help?

```
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
...
\title{
\selectlanguage{russian}
Успех в Америке
\selectlanguage{english}
Success in America \\ \vspace{2 mm} {\large Exploring Ukrainian-American Transnationalism}}
```

Comment: In what environment? With Fedora 18 and Texlive there seems to be no problems (at least on pdflatex). I installed texlive-hyphen-russian, texlive-lang-cyrillic, texlive-cyrillic and texlive-collection-langcyrillic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimum working example of XeLaTeX code that you can play with (IMPORTANT:  replace the fonts I have chosen, eg `Linux Libertine O` with fonts on your system!).  There are some errors in your code that suggest you may benefit from switching now (early) to XeLaTeX, which SEEMS to be better for multiple languages.  I hope this is helpful.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine Mono O}

% BEGIN

\begin{document}

% BODY

Успех в Америке

Success in America

{\large Exploring Ukrainian-American Transnationalism}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This one did the job. PDF printed nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Next level (typesetting longer Ukrainian passages):  either follow egreg's instructions below, or learn how to implement `polyglossia` in XeLaTeX...these are your avenues for getting correct hyphenation, etc.  I think.  Haven't tackled it yet myself, as I typically only include small snippets of foreign languages.

Answer (score 6):

There's rarely a need for using `\selectlanguage` directly; it may be useful if the document changes completely the language from some point on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\title{Успех в Америке\\
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
Success in America \\[2mm]
{\large Exploring Ukrainian-American Transnationalism}
\end{otherlanguage*}}

\author{???}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Recall that the last specified encoding and the last specified language are the default for the document. Parts of the document written in another language are to be marked with

1. `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}`, which changes everything (tags included)
2. `\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}`, which changes hyphenation rules, shortcuts and typographic rules
3. `\foreignlanguage{english}{text}` for small parts, but it's mostly equivalent to the `otherlanguage*` environment
4. `\begin{hyphenrules}{english}`, which only changes the hyphenation rules (and is not useful for your purposes).

As you see from the picture, the date is in Russian, which is defined as the base language.

[image]

Comment: I will look this over once I get back to my computer.